Image uploading isn't working
When attempting to upload an image, either via chat or via the main site, I'm shown "An error occured, please try again".
For (perhaps obvious) reasons, I can't upload a screenshot to demonstrate this, so here's a temporary imgur one for now:


Confirmed here - I was just writing a similar post to report this. So it's not only affecting a single user or a single network etc.

Came here to report the same at space stack exchange.

Reproduced by lyxal and Rydwolf Programs in chat

I've notified our Site Reliability Engineering team (though I believe I can see this generated an automated alert as well). Find further updates on StackStatus. I (or another employee) will mark this [status-completed] when it is resolved.

The issue got fixed at around 2024-08-16 00:43:00Z (± 1 minute). Tested on Meta.SE and ELL.SE.
Demo:


Can confirm it is working again now. Came here to say that... and you beat me to it. And I am cheating with internal knowledge.

I am pretty sure you got the timestamp right to within 30 seconds. What the heck?

I also would like to report that the issue is fixed
